# Cannot install my npm package.json

Tags: npm, npm-install, package.json

I'm struggling to install my `package.json`

I delete my `node_modules` folder and trying to re-install all the stuff

I'm getting errors

```js
npm WARN deprecated fs-promise@1.0.0: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with Promise Support
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! Command failed: /usr/bin/git clone --depth=1 -q -b master https://github.com/jlongster/ast-types.git /Users/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-1000c12c
npm ERR! /Users/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-1000c12c/.git: Permission denied
npm ERR! 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/.npm/_logs/2017-09-06T19_29_56_831Z-debug.log
```

i tried to clear cache both normally and with `-- force` but it doesn't help.

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe run as root, or as administrator

Comment: already made `sudo npm install` didn't help

Answer (score 0):

As there is a `\Users` folder you are probably on a mac. Normally .npm folders are located within the user folders, e.g. `/Users/username/.npm`.

You will probably find one in your `$HOME` directory:

```
ls -la ~
```

If you run this command:

```
/usr/bin/git clone --depth=1 -q -b master https://github.com/jlongster/ast-types.git /Users/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-1000c12c
```

with the addition of your `<username>`, it should work:

```
/usr/bin/git clone --depth=1 -q -b master https://github.com/jlongster/ast-types.git /Users/<username>/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-1000c12c
```

Somewhere in your package.json there is a package depending on this git repo. The log file should have some more clues:

```
locate 2017-09-06T19_29_56_831Z-debug.log | xargs cat
```